# ruby -method that return true if sum of 2 arg = n

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the appropriate Method that takes 2 arguments array and n , and return true if sum of   2 array elements   = n using ruby? 
i know detect and inject(:+) but don't know how to combine both of them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#combination`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) if the array length can be more than 2.

`combination(2)` returns all the combinations of length 2 and then `any?` returns true if at least one combination has sum `n`.

```
def foo(arr,n)  
  arr.combination(2).any?{|a,b| a + b == n}
end

foo [1,2,3,4,5], 3 #=> true
foo [1,2,3,4,5], 10 #=> false
```

Comment: I tried this and worked thnx for ur help                          def sum_to_n?(array,n)
array.combination(2).any? { |a, b| a + b == n }
end

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this is a useful function, but here you go

```
def weird_function arr, n
  return arr[0] + arr[1] === n
end
```

Usage

```
weird_function [1,3], 4 #=> true
weird_function [1,2], 4 #=> false
```